# jQuery addClass and IE - not adding class

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, addclass

Well, all works fine under FireFox or Chrome but I'm not able to have added class under IE8/IE10

Code is simple

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".mattblackmenu").addClass("ie10");
    });
```

Link to the site with that code: http://www.nestcasa.com/

Any clue what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to work fine here (ie10).

Comment: ie8 does not fully support html5. Also, make sure your markup is valid.

Comment: @karthikr - it will be used with conditional statement for IE10 anyway, but I'm not able to get this to work even without under IE10

Comment: @JackTheKnife Conditional comments are unsupported in IE10.

Comment: @ajp15243 I know that - conditional withing jQuery. That's why I'm trying to add that class to fix some issues under IE10 and CSS

Comment: @JackTheKnife You're using jQuery 1.4.2, which is rather out of date at this point. Is there a reason you're not using something more recent? Even jQuery 1.9.x supports back to IE6 if old browser compatibility is an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This suggestion is not really an answer but it's too long to fit in a comment.

Change your code to this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var menu = jQuery(".mattblackmenu");

    if(menu.length == 0)
        alert("Could not any matt black menus");
    else
        alert("did find a matt black menu");

    jQuery(".mattblackmenu").addClass("ie10");
});
```

Then you will be able to narrow down whether your problems are with your menu item(s) not being found or with your CSS.

Comment: You can always link to a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code in your comment.

Comment: OK, added that code to the site - is finding but not adding new class.

Comment: I tried looking at your page with IE10 and using *Developer Tools*. Your page is referencing lots of CSS files but not the ones that look like they will have the styles for the `ie10` class. So presently although the `<div>` gets the `ie10` class it doesn't have any effect on how it looks. Try getting rid of the conditional comments (as suggested by @ajp15243) so your IE-related styles can change the div.

Comment: @JackTheKnife Yeah, I'm seeing your `.mattblackmenu` element is getting the `ie10` class, you just won't see any styling because your styles-ie10.css file is beind a `gt IE 9` conditional comment, which IE10 will *not* pay attention to because, as I mentioned, it doesn't support conditional comments. So the class is being added, but the styles pulled into the page don't end up including anything that would target `.ie10`, from the looks of it.

Comment: @ajp15243 I have added class ie10 to default styles.css but still I'm not able to see 'ie10' added to that div no matter what on my computer.

Comment: @JackTheKnife Oh derp, spoke too soon, I saw it added on Chrome and forgot for a moment that you were having an issue adding the class on IE10. This is what happens when you do too much multitasking. Have you tried a more recent version of jQuery as I suggested in the question comments?

Comment: Making this response as an answer, because somehow got fixed issue following all directions above. Issue with not getting displayed on my computer was related to the Magento cache :\

Comment: @ajp15243 It looks like I have got this to work with conditional jQuery to load class 'ie10' when IE10 is present. To replace jQuery with something new - so far I'm not able to localize Magento block which loads that file as default core part :\